# How does matplotlib decide what to display when the data size is larger than axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a dataset where the size of the data arrays is larger than the size of the figure, even larger than the resolution of my screen.  As shown in the example below, matplotlib does a remarkably good job rendering the data. This is just an example dataset.  My real dataset is far more unpredictable.  I have a concern there may be occasions when some important data is not shown. How does matplotlib decide what to show?

```
x = np.arange(0, 10000)
y = np.zeros(10000)
for i in range(0, 10000, 100):
    y[i] = x[i]
x_spikes = np.random.choice(x, size=10, replace=False)
y[x_spikes] = 10000 + x[x_spikes]   
plt.plot(x,y);

print(sorted(x_spikes))
[375, 2828, 3494, 6526, 6855, 6902, 6923, 7117, 7831, 9558]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand? Matplotlib shows all data? how can you array be bigger than the figure size?

Comment: @FChm Thanks for asking. The resolution of my screen is 1920x1080.  The figure is even smaller.  The data array has 10000 elements, so not all elements can be rendered.

Comment: I don't actually know what matplotlib does, but imagine it plots them all - if more than one fall on the same pixel, that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plt.plot` command creates one or more `Line2D` objects. Those lines have a `linewidth`. The unit of the linewidth is points (the default being 1.5 points).

Independent of the pixel resolution all data is hence shown, no data is lost.

What can happen though is that if you make the linewidth very narrow, features may get lost due to antialiasing. 
To ensure that is not happening you may always use a linewidth which is at least ppi/dpi. I.e. 72/dpi in the matplotlib case. The default dpi is 100. So as long as the linewidth is greater or equal `0.72` points, all points are shown. (In Juypter often the default dpi is 72, hence 72/72==1, and a linewidth of `1` would be needed.)

All of this applies to lines. For bar plots (where the width is in data coordinates) this is different. Also images might not show all data - though `imshow` has the `interpolation` argument to allow to steer the interpolating behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  In the case of a bar chart, what is the right way to calculate line width?  For example, data width is 5 million and I'm rendering to a png file with a known figure size?

Comment: WIthout needing to calculate anything, if you give the bars an edge, like `plt.bar(..., linewidth=1, edgecolor="black")` the same argument as for lines above holds, I.e. as long as the linewidth is larger or equal a pixel, it will be shown. If instead you want to calculate the actual bar width it's complicated. You need to find out the fraction the axes takes of the total figure size (via the subplot params), calculate the number of pixels it contains (via the figure dpi) and make sure each bar is at least `data range / axes pixel size` in width.